# SQL Server, Problem creating temp table in TSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, temp-tables

Hi when i execute the following TSQL, i get the error message below. But there is nothing wrong with the SQL syntax is there?

```
create table #tb ([t1] tinyint, [t2] varchar(50))
insert into #tb values
    (1, 'a'), 
    (2, 'b')
```

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near ','.

There is nothing else in the SQL query window. Running SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As jmoreno mentions, the`VALUES (), ()` syntax is SQL Server 2008+ supported but you tagged this as SQL Server 2005.

Use:

```
CREATE TABLE #tb ([t1] tinyint, [t2] varchar(50))

INSERT INTO #tb 
SELECT 1, 'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b'
```

It's also possible to do this in a single query, using the [`SELECT ... INTO` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx), but the temp table can't already exist:

```
SELECT *
  INTO #tb
  FROM (SELECT CAST(1 AS TINYINT) AS t1, 
               CAST('a' AS VARCHAR(50)) AS t2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 2, 'b') x
```

Comment: OMG Ponies I just had to upvote your year and half old answer because of "x".  I thought that had to be a typo at the end of the FROM statement but it wasn't and it sure helps me a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
create table #tb ([t1] tinyint, [t2] varchar(50));
insert into #tb ([t1], [t2])
values(1, 'a'), (2, 'b')
```

You need to specify the columns that you're inserting into.

//EDIT

Sorry, SQL 2005 syntax below. It's not nearly as elegant.

```
CREATE TABLE #tb ([t1] TINYINT, [t2] VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #tb
SELECT 1, 'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'b'
```

Answer (score 1):

You say you're using SQL 2005, but the VALUES (), () syntax wasn't implemented until 2008.

Comment: oh ok.. then how do i re-write it?

Comment: Multiple insert statements, or a select and UNION ALL.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to insert two rows, so you need to insert the first row and then the second instead of trying to squeeze it all into one:

```
CREATE TABLE #tb ([t1] TINYINT, [t2] VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO #tb([t1],[t2]) VALUES (1, 'a'); --row 1
INSERT INTO #tb([t1],[t2]) VALUES (2, 'b'); --row 2

--see if it worked
SELECT [t1], [t2] 
FROM #tb

--clean up the temp table when you're done
DROP TABLE #tb
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT t.field1, t.field2 INTO #myTempTable

FROM myDB.myOwner.myTable t

WHERE ...

ORDER BY t.field1, t.field2;

-- use ##myTempTable as the name if you want your table to be GLOBAL.